# TensorFlow model from AutoML throwing TF_INVALID_ARGUMENT when using TensorFlow C API with CppFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am just getting started with TensorFlow, and trying to use [CppFlow](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow) to run object detection using a model I've created using Google's [AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/). I've run the training, and tested it online and it's working fine. However, I need to be able to use it offline, so I've downloaded the model (.pb) according to their [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/export-edge?hl=ru#deploy-example-web). It's failing on even initialising the model. It works fine with the ssd_inception model:

```
Model model("../ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/frozen_inference_graph.pb"); // THIS WORKS
Model model("../Test/frozen_inference_graph.pb"); // THIS FAILS
```

The constructor for Model (from Model.cpp in CppFlow):

```
Model::Model(const std::string& model_filename) {

    this->status = TF_NewStatus();
    this->graph = TF_NewGraph();

    // Create the session.
    TF_SessionOptions* sess_opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();

    this->session = TF_NewSession(this->graph, sess_opts, this->status);
    TF_DeleteSessionOptions(sess_opts);

    // Check the status
    this->status_check(true);

    // Create the graph
    TF_Graph* g = this->graph;


    // Import the graph definition
    TF_Buffer* def = read(model_filename);
    this->error_check(def != nullptr, "An error occurred reading the model");

    TF_ImportGraphDefOptions* graph_opts = TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions();
    TF_GraphImportGraphDef(g, def, graph_opts, this->status);
    TF_DeleteImportGraphDefOptions(graph_opts);
    TF_DeleteBuffer(def);


    this->status_check(true);
}
```

The final status check returns a TF_INVALID_ARGUMENT and so throws an exception.

I have no idea why this would be the case. I know the model works for object detection (when used online), and there is no error on the line where the model is being read (TF_Buffer* def = read(model_filename);) so I'm not sure why this would be failing. What is the invalid argument in question here? Is the model coming from AutoML of a different kind than what would be accepted here?

Totally clueless, all help massively appreciated.